# Weird characters on x509 certificate

Tags: java, x509, asn.1

I'm trying to open/parse a public key of an X509 Certificate and retrieve a specific information from the file.
I'm using Java as the language to do it although i only started writing Java a couple weeks ago, so noob here :)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class CertificateTest {
public static void main (String[] args) throws CertificateException, IOException{

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("CertificateFile.pem");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);

    System.out.print(cert);

    }    
}
```

Ok so i'm able to parse the file and print it on the console, but the file doesn't "render" well..
Some parts of the file seems to be ok, but others are just like this:

```
0E.!.....W>._...
.....Q.9.u-U....
P...". ^..6...>Q
U.3..I.k....K...
.e.....
```

What i want to retrieve is:

```
System.out.print(cert.getSubjectUniqueID());
```

And it returns null. This could be right because this is an optional field, but i am almost certain that the field is present.

And when i print the method

```
System.out.print(cert.getSubjectX500Principal());
```

Output is:

```
OID.2.5.4.45=#03090090B3D51F30020000, OU=03
```

The byte string: 90B3D51F30020000 is in fact what i want to retrieve from the file, so it's why i think .getSubjectUniqueID should return this value. Or the entire string 03090090B3D51F30020000.

This file is encoded with ASN1 notation.

So, if anyone could provide some insights on what is going on here i would be much appreciated. As i feel that my knowledge stops here. And i already searched a lot and couldn't find any issue similar to this one.
Regards.

Comment: Why not, at first, avoid java and first check with a Certificate Viewer like (taken from first few google search results): [MMC Snap-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx), [Online Certificate Viewer](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/tool_certview.html), [CSR Decoder And Certificate Decoder](https://certlogik.com/decoder/) to verify that *that* field does in-fact exist, and *then* if so, attempt a Java implementation? Just seems like a quick way to check what you are looking first, then code it.